# Is it unwise to attempt to anger other drivers who are exiting the highway?

Tags: conflict-aversion, awkward-situations, conflicts

There have been many times while driving on the highway when another car has suddenly cut into my lane in order to get over to the right-most lane so they can exit the highway, and I had to slam on the brakes to avoid hitting that car. I have chosen not to immediately vent my anger at that person because I don't want to create a road-rage incident.

What I usually have done instead was to wait until that car was halfway up the exit ramp, then I beeped to get their attention, and then I visually expressed my anger towards that person.

Recently, a friend of mine was traveling with me in my car when once again another driver cut into my lane to exit the highway. I then waited to beep and visually express my anger until he was half way up on the exit ramp.

After I did this my friend said that I acted cowardly by waiting until the other driver was unable to chase after me and visually express his anger. At first I thought he was joking but he was quite serious. I told him that I do this to avoid road-rage incidents, but he thought what I did was unwise.

He said regardless of my reasons for doing it, it was still a cowardly act and I should instead be 'man enough' to vent my anger at another driver up close instead from a position in which the other driver is unable to retaliate. He believes my cowardly act of revenge may enrage the other driver and may motivate him to get back on the highway and chase after me, thus creating a road-rage incident.

Is it unwise then to attempt to anger other drivers who are exiting the highway?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately as explained in [help/on-topic] questions which ask us to adjudicate “right” and “wrong” in a situation are off-topic, as they only generate opinions on who is correct rather than resolving the actual issue and teaching interpersonal skills.

Comment: @ paparazzo, I guess what it all comes down to is whether it is wise to express any emotion to any act of bad driving by other drivers, and I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I get it. I have often wished that I was driving a James Bond spy car which could pop out dual 50 cal machine guns and give a bad driver a burst.

However, you and your friend are both wrong. Doing anything to escalate a driving mistake into a road rage incident is nuts. Refraining from escalating a situation isn't cowardly, it is the mature response. Getting into a demolition derby or a fight with some idiot is insane.

Comment: Good answer, but in addition to escalation increasing risks it's worth pointing out that there is *absolutely no upside*. It accomplishes absolutely nothing, whether you do it immediately or later.